# How can I get the message menu and other Unity notification area widgets into my Awesome WM panel?

Tags: unity, awesome

I've just started using Awesome WM, but I miss a lot of stuff from the Unity panel: the logout buttons, the message menu, etc. Is there a way to get these into the Awesome WM panel?

Comment: Is is specifically the Unity indicators you want, or are similar replacements suitable?

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, its not possible to add the actual indicators from Unity into Awesome's panel, but you can add things to Awesome's panel by configuring its text based config file. the Awesome wiki has more details about this: http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Awesome_3_configuration

Basically you can add text, widgets and such, but not indicators.